# People tracking across different cameras

Tags: vision

I'm trying to develop a solution that can track/recognize people with multiple cameras (raspberry pis) in a room. The idea is to track the path of one person in one/multiple rooms.

Solution would be to use raspberry pis, detects motion and send images to a backend solution which then implement an opensource solution or make use of multiple third party libraries.

For the moment we are only using Face recognition to recognize people in different images, but the solution is not good as it is only accurate with front face images and it is quite slow. Do you have other ideas on what can be done to improve results? Color tracking? Clothes recognition? Any third parties/opensource solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: take a piece of paper and a pen, then write down 10 low frequency features that make you look different from your mother...
body volume, cloths colour, fabric patterns, hair colour, hair volume, you name it. if you track their movement you can predecit when they will leave one field of fiew and which field of view the will enter next...

Comment: Hello, how can you track such parts of a person? Do you have any reference ?

Comment: Use picture instead of stream is little bit rate overhead.. Stream using all the  capabilities calculate and not transfer what is not necessary. Anyway Rpi do not have power to handle Multi cameras and also to code video from multi cam into H256 HEVC anyway..